# Is it possible to bend a shape in various directions and keep the texture in place as if it was printed material?

Tags: modeling, texturing

In real life I can print out a pattern onto a material, (which bends but isn't stretchy), cut out its shape and then stitch it together to make a 3D object.

I want to create mock-ups from the same 2D pattern by applying it as a texture to the same shape as the real life cut-out, which is bent in Blendr in the same way that it would be in real life.

Is this even possible, or will I have to recreate the finished shape in Blendr, create a UV map, and use other software to translate the 2D print to the UV map, then apply that to the object in Blendr? Or something else?

As a simple example this shows a 2D print and the 3D item. A and B are holes, which are rivetted together.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please show some image or drawing in order to understand better?

Comment: @moonbots sure, updated.

Comment: Yes.  For example, try menu File::Import::Images_as_planes to get a picture image into blender.  Then for the plane, in Edit mode, RMB (right-mouse-btn) subdivide several times.  Then apply a SimpleDeform modifier and select Twist and change the angle around.   That proves it can be done.

Comment: You don't need other software to translate an image to the UV map. The thing with a UV map is, you can create it when the object is completely flat and simply use it to display the image. Then you can bend the object and the image stays placed on the faces according to the UV layout of the flat object - that's how you would do for example a cloth simulation of a flag waving in the wind. The only problem here is, depending on how much you want to bend the object, if there is enough geometry to accomplish those shapes without stretching the faces (and thus stretching the image as well).